# What is the appropriate court for an action relating to a breach of the Human Rights Act 1998 (HRA)?

Tags: england-and-wales, human-rights, civil

See [Why must claims against the police for human rights act breaches be brought within 1 year?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89459/why-must-claims-against-the-police-for-human-rights-act-breaches-be-brought-with)

If a public body acts contrary to one’s convention rights, what is the appropriate court in which to take action against them, and what form should be used?

Comment: It depends on what the claim is for (e.g. just money or for an order of restitution etc) and its financial value - more or less than £10,000

Answer (score 1):

The procedures on starting a claim are covered within [Part 7](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1998/3132/part/7?timeline=false) and [Practice Direction 7A](https://www.justice.gov.uk/courts/procedure-rules/civil/rules/part07/pd_part07a) (PD7A) of the Civil Procedure Rules.

PD7A, at paragraph 3.1, states:

> A claimant must use form N1 to start a claim under Part 7.

And at paragraph 2.11(1):

> The normal rules apply in deciding in which court and specialist list a claim that includes issues under the Human Rights Act 1998 should be started. They also apply in deciding which procedure to use to start the claim;

There are a number of provisions and variations at PD7A (from para 2.1 to 2.11), but if the value of the claim is less than £10,000 one can submit it using Money Claim On Line [MCOL](https://www.gov.uk/make-court-claim-for-money/make-claim).

Or, one can post [Claim Form N1](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/form-n1-claim-form-cpr-part-7) to the County Court, remembering to answer the question on page 2:

> Does, or will, your claim include any issues under the Human Rights Act 1998?